# Generate a ID, check if it exists, if yes loop until new ID is generated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure what is wrong with below logic. Task is to generate a ID, check if it exists in the file(Sample.txt) and if it is already there then generate a new code until a unique one is created. Whenever a unique ID is created at the initial stage it will goto else loop. In case if an existing ID is generated it will first goto if loop, generate a new ID but then will not compare it again, instead directly jump to else loop adding duplicate ID to the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import string
import os.path

# Take user inputs

NetID = input("Enter the NetID: ")
CompTemp = input("Enter the Compliance template: ")
Channel = input("Enter the Channel: ")
Env = input ("Enter the environment 'P' or 'T': ")
Const = "WG"
Var1 = str((random.randint(0,9)))
Var2 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
#i=0

FSID=Const+Channel+NetID+Var1+Env
print("Original FSID: ", FSID)

datafile = "C:\\Work\\Sample.txt"
f2=open(datafile)

# Define function
def CrtFSID():
    """ Generate FSID"""
    global FSID
    Var1 = str((random.randint(0,9)))
    FSID = Const+Channel+NetID+Var1+Env
    print("New FSID code case 1: ", FSID)
    return FSID

for line in open("C:\\Work\\Sample.txt", "r"):
    if FSID in f2.read():
        print("generate new FSID code")
        CrtFSID()
        print("Changed FSID is: ", FSID)
        continue
   else:
       f=open(datafile, "a")
       f.write("Adding new FSID %s\r\n" % FSID)
       print("I am in else loop")
       f.close()
       break

print("Unique FSID added into the file: ", FSID)
```

The Shell output:

```
Enter the NetID: KL123
Enter the Compliance template: ABC_01
Enter the Channel: TB
Enter the environment 'P' or 'T': P
Original FSID:  WGTBKL1239P

generate new FSID code
New FSID code case 1:  WGTBKL1237P
Changed FSID is:  WGTBKL1237P

I am in else loop
Unique FSID added into the file:  WGTBKL1237P
```

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Comment: If my file already has WGTBKL1237P and WGTBKL1239P, Output should be added to the file Sample.txt in the format "WGTBKL1236P", the random generated second last digit due to Var1.

Comment: When you run the code, if the new ID is generated by function, then this new ID is not checked in the if loop, after continue statement the program will goto for loop and directly to else loop as shown in the shell output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop in the later part of your code has some problems. You're looping over the lines of your file, but you don't actually use the lines at all, you're separately reading the file from another file object. And that only works the first iteration, because after calling `read` on the file once, the file object will be at the end of the file and there is nothing left to read. Therefore your code always accepts the second ID you try, even if it's invalid too.

You can fix this by reading the file only once, and saving its text to a variable that you test against. I also suggest changing to a `while` loop, since you want to keep going until you find a valid ID:

```
datafile = "C:\\Work\\Sample.txt"
with open(datafile) as f2:
    text = f2.read()

# ...

while True:
    if FSID in text:
        print("generate new FSID code")
        CrtFSID()
        print("Changed FSID is: ", FSID)
   else:
       with open(datafile, "a") as f:
          f.write("Adding new FSID %s\r\n" % FSID)
       print("I am in else loop")
       break
```

Note that this code may still behave badly if most of the IDs you can generate are already in the file. In the worst case, they're all taken and it will loop forever! You might consider exhaustively looping over the digits you can put in the ID, rather than just picking one randomly. That way you can tell for sure that you've tried them all and give up (giving an appropriate error message perhaps).

After reviewing this answer, I realized that you can simplify the loop even further by using `if`'s condition as the `while` loop's condition. The `else` block turns into top-level code after the loop ends on its own (no more need for `break`):

```
while FSID in text:
    print("generate new FSID code")
    CrtFSID()
    print("Changed FSID is: ", FSID)

with open(datafile, "a") as f:
    f.write("Adding new FSID %s\r\n" % FSID)

print("done")
```

A final note: While it's not the cause of your current issue, using a function to modify a global variable is usually not great code design. A better approach is to have a function `return` a new value, and the calling code can use that to update the variable as needed.

Comment: I just edited my answer to improve it in a few ways. I somehow failed to notice last night that the `while` loop could take care of the condition checking you were doing with your `if` and `else`, so the code can get much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
if FSID in f2.read():
    print("generate new FSID code")
    CrtFSID()
    print("Changed FSID is: ", FSID)
    continue
```

Suppose Unique ID is 12 and it existed in file, according to your logic we are in if loop right now. Here, you are creating new Unique ID(`CrtFSID()`). What if the created ID also exists in file?? You are not handling that case.

Use

```
file = f2.read()
while FSID in file:
    FSID = crtFSID()
f=open(datafile, "a")
f.write("Adding new FSID %s\r\n" % FSID)
print("I am in else loop")
f.close()
```

Comment: The `CrtFSID` function modifies the global `FSID` variable, so the main premise of this answer seems wrong to me. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I did modify the variable because the first declared FSID was not getting changed to newly created FSID as in function. This was a problem during comparison in if loop, so I made it global.

Comment: @Venkatesh, making the variable global worked out for comparison but then as I used wrong if loop structure it was not consuming the new one for comparison. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate new `fsid` and check whether it is in `Sample.txt` or not. If not - generate new `fsid` and repeat the check. If yes - write it to the `Sample.txt` and break the loop:

```
import random

net_id = input('Enter the NetID: ')
channel = input('Enter the Channel: ')
env = input('Enter the environment "P" or "T": ')
with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

while True:
    fsid = 'WG{}{}{}{}'.format(channel, net_id, random.randint(0, 9), env)
    if fsid not in data:
        with open('Sample.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(fsid)
        break
print('Unique FSID added into the file: {}'.format(fsid))
```

Output:

```
Enter the NetID: KL123
Enter the Channel: TB
Enter the environment "P" or "T": P
Unique FSID added into the file: WGTBKL1237P
```

Comment: Thank you Alderven for the solution, this works as well.